# Could not find or load main class - for any program

Tags: java, linux, shell, javac

I'm having a problem where the `java` command - no matter what I'm trying to run, says that it `Could not find or load main class`.

Everything is fine when compiling with javac, `.class` files are created. So when I run:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

on

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

everything compiles fine, a `HelloWorld.class` file is created along side the `HelloWorld.java` file. However when I then go to run:

```
java HelloWorld
```

1) the most telling sign is that when I press `Tab` to autofill `HelloWorld` nothing comes up.

2) when I do run it, I get the `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld` despite it being in the same directory, not being part of a package, compiling fine with a `.class` file, the program having a main class.

For reference running `Fedora 23 64bit, openjdk version "1.8.0_111"`.

Comment: can you type `javac -version` and `java version` in your cmd line and add the input to your question? Unless this solves your issue by some blatantly wrong result

Comment: @RyanTurnbull perhaps I should have been more specific in the post, when i run `java -version` the version specified is:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_111"`
`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (1.8.0_111-b16)`
`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b16, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `java -cp . HelloWorld`

Some good reading: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Comment: That's embarrassing, something I should have been able to work out myself, so my question now is why have I been able to run `java HelloWorld` with out any hitches up until now on different machines?

Comment: It is likely your classpath was incorrect on this particular machine.You can check it by using `echo $PATH` , and fix it following this: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/classpath.html

Answer (score 4):

Just a small reminder for the newbies in Java:

When compiling, you type:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

Now, you've got two files:

```
MyClass.class MyClass.java
```

Now, whereas you typed the .java extension when compiling, you must NOT type the extension .class when running the program. You should just type:

```
java MyClass
```

If you type `java MyClass.class` then you'll get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify classpath parameter while running your example:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

Comment: This still returns "Could not find or load main class" and I have no idea why. I'm in the same directory as the class itself. Java has the worst CLI tools, I cringe every time I have to use them

Comment: @Amalgovinus: Just letting you know I have the same problem and I've been using java for almost 25 years.  No idea what is going on; works fine on a linux vm, but not on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

`java -cp HelloWorld` 
works.  I use windows 10, and was checking out the very course.  I first had to add it to path, and spent time wasted on it.  Be sure, however, to **NOT** include the `.class` part of the name.  Java is not my first language, but Java is portable and is a suitable language for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me while compiling a piece of code (that was initially writen for an IDE with several files) throug terminal. The problem was mentioning the package with the same name of the main class (package HelloWorld). I fixed it and now it works. Not sure if that's your case

Answer (score -1):

May be you have removed your JDK From System.
You can change it using following steps

---

1> `Select Project`

---

2> Right Click On `Project`

---

3> Click On `Properties`

---

4> Go to `Java Build Path`

---

5> Click On `Libraries` Option

---

6> Select `JRE System Library`

---

7> Click On `Edit`

---

8> Change Your `Library` Accordingly

---

Comment: Why do you think JDK is removed if the original post says **"everything compiles fine"**? Also, where is that "Select project" option that you mentioned? The question is about the *command line* usage of the `java` command.